# How to do date offset using np.where

Tags: pandas

My dataframe `data['date']` is below

```
0         61-1_1
1         61-1_2
2         61-1_3
3         61-1_4
4         61-1_5
```

How to apply my `data['date']=data.date-pd.DateOffset(years=100)` using `np.where`

Comment: There is some condition if need `np.where`?

Comment: @jezrael panda do from 1970, where before . so normal 61 I need to offset 100 years using np.where

Comment: @jezrael `np.where(data['date].dt.year > current_year, data - pd.DateOffset(years=100), data)`

Comment: I am a bit confused, your solution not working?

Comment: @jezrael if data['date'] > current year then we have to give offset(100 years) other wise we need to give current year only

Comment: `test= pd.Series(["2059-09-07","2055-01-01","2047-12-15","2042-07-11"])`; `dtype: datetime64[ns]`
; `test= pd.Series(np.where(test.dt.year > current_year, test- pd.DateOffset(years=100), test))`

Comment: @jezrael, small example I put in above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want subtract all datetimes above today year your solution working, only small change for `data['date']` instead `data`:

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'], format='%y-%m_%d')
print (data)
        date
0 2061-01-01
1 2061-01-02
2 2061-01-03
3 2061-01-04
4 2061-01-05

current_year = pd.to_datetime('now').year
data['date'] = np.where(data['date'].dt.year > current_year, 
                        data['date'] - pd.DateOffset(years=100), 
                        data['date'])
print (data)
        date
0 1961-01-01
1 1961-01-02
2 1961-01-03
3 1961-01-04
4 1961-01-05
```